# Using VBA script to highlight cells based on a formula from the active cell

Tags: excel, vba

Let's start with my spreadsheet & code so far (cleaned up to remove irrelevant and personal information):

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | Who | How Much | What Day | Notes |
| 23 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 10 | 1 |  |
| 24 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 25 | 1 |  |
| 25 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 35 | 2 |  |
| 26 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 32 | 5 |  |
| 27 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 21 | 8 |  |
| 28 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 32 | 8 |  |
| 29 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 1 | 9 |  |
| 30 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 29 | 9 |  |
| 31 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 3 | 10 |  |
| 32 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 13 | 12 |  |
| 33 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 5 | 15 |  |
| 34 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 6 | 15 |  |
| 35 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 32 | 17 |  |
| 36 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 20 | 20 |  |
| 37 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 30 | 21 |  |
| 38 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 2 | 26 |  |
| 39 | HE WHO MUST NOT BE NAMED | 15 | 26 |  |
| 40 |  |  |  |  |
| 41 | Pay date | Bill Total | Additional | Carrying Balance |
| 42 | 22-Oct | 119 |  |  |
| 43 | 5-Nov | 174 |  |  |
| 44 | 19-Nov | 137 |  |  |
| 45 | 3-Dec | 142 |  |  |
| 46 | 17-Dec | 99 |  |  |
| 47 | 31-Dec | 201 |  |  |
| 48 | 14-Jan | 110 |  |  |
| 49 | 28-Jan | 188 |  |  |
| 50 | 11-Feb | 106 |  |  |
| 51 | 25-Feb | 205 |  |  |
| 52 | 11-Mar | 106 |  |  |
| 53 | 25-Mar | 172 |  |  |
| 54 | 8-Apr | 192 |  |  |
| 55 | 22-Apr | 119 |  |  |
| 56 | 6-May | 142 |  |  |
| 57 | 20-May | 137 |  |  |
| 58 | 3-Jun | 142 |  |  |
| 59 | 17-Jun | 134 |  |  |
| 60 | 1-Jul | 201 |  |  |
| 61 | 15-Jul | 110 |  |  |
| 62 | 29-Jul | 201 |  |  |
| 63 | 12-Aug | 106 |  |  |
| 64 | 26-Aug | 202 |  |  |
| 65 | 9-Sep | 139 |  |  |
| 66 | 23-Sep | 119 |  |  |
| 67 | 7-Oct | 162 |  |  |
| 68 | 21-Oct | 117 |  |  |
| 69 | 4-Nov | 174 |  |  |
| 70 | 18-Nov | 137 |  |  |
| 71 | 2-Dec | 177 |  |  |
| 72 | 16-Dec | 99 |  |  |
| 73 | 30-Dec | 212 |  |  |
| 74 | 16-Jan | 0 |  |  |

This function:

```
Sub HighLightCells()
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
Dim day As Range
For Each day In Range("Table1[What Day]")
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=IF(MONTH(Cells(ActiveCell.Row,1))=MONTH(Cells(ActiveCell.Row+1,1)),AND(day>=DAY(Cells(ActiveCell.Row,1)),day<DAY(Cells(ActiveCell.Row+1,1))),OR(day>=DAY(Cells(ActiveCell.Row,1)),day<=DAY(Cells(ActiveCell.Row+1,1))))"
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Next day
End Sub
```

This is in the sheet's code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Call HighLightCells
End Sub
```

What am I trying to accomplish? Yesterday I had some assistance creating a script to add up all of my bills according to what day they fell in my pay checks. The formula I am using for that (the entire Bill Total column):

```
=IF(MONTH(A42)=MONTH(A43),SUMIFS(Table1[How Much],Table1[What Day],">="&DAY(A42),Table1[What Day],"<"&DAY(A43)),SUMIF(Table1[What Day],">="&DAY(A42),Table1[How Much])+SUMIF(Table1[What Day],"<="&DAY(A43),Table1[How Much]))
```

Now, I am trying to use VBA to highlight the bills that are due within a specific pay period when I click on the row in the table that correlates with that pay period. Right now I have the macro set to the entire sheet, but it would be nice if I could get it to only work on the range of the table (which is named "Table3")
So basically, if I clicked on row 44 which has a pay date of Nov 19, I would like for it to highlight all of the bills due between Nov 19 and Dec 3 (the formula to sum it is above, which is what I am basing this highlight off as well).
Where am I right now with my code: The Formula1 I am using works if I replace the variable "day" and replace the information contained within DAY() to an actual cell. When I do this in the actual VBA script, it takes around 30 seconds (as if it is cycling through almost an infinite loop) and then stops and nothing is highlighted. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Version: O365 on Windows

Comment: Guessing Pay date, Bill Total, Additional, and Carrying Balance are actually in columns E, F, G, and H? No matter. Right away it looks like your `MONTH( ... = MONTH(...` IF condition won't work for Nov 19 to Dec 3. `DateDiff("d", Cells(Selection.Row+1,1), Cells(Selection.Row,1),...) <=14` might work. (`Selection` substituted for `Activecell` there but probably makes no difference.) Nice job on that `AND(` construction, but there should be a simpler, easier to hold-in-the-head way. I'll try and take a look after 5PM EST.

Comment: To restrict the affected range, put a `If Intersect(activecell, ["Table3" or some address]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` at the top of  `Sub HighLightCells()`.

Comment: @klausnrooster I have now added the restriction and that portion works. Thank you for that. Were you able to take a look at the formula? I'm still struggling with this one and was circling back to it today. 
I'm not sure if the Month=Month condition would have any kind of issue, but I know it works in the formula format that I am using it for, perhaps there is a difference with the VBA though.

Comment: so Table1 is layed out exactly as your question shows it above, and not the way I guessed at the top of my first comment?

Comment: can you put a file up on PasteBin or another site?